# GNU Make: sed doesn't work when piped inside of $(shell)

Tags: shell, makefile, pipe, gnu

Here is my experimental Makefile.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

~/hello.txt:  $(shell echo '$$(@D)/')$(shell echo '$$(@F)' | sed -e 's/hello/bye/')
    echo "$^"
```

Somehow the sed command doesn't work, and Make complains about circular dependency

```
gmake: Circular /users/sim/hello.txt <- /users/me/hello.txt dependency dropped.
gmake: *** No rule to make target `echo', needed by `/users/me/hello.txt'.  Stop.
```

My expected behavior was GNU Make looking for ~/bye.txt instead. What am I doing wrong?

Although I can just specify "bye.txt" explicitly in this small example, I'd still like to know why sed command doesn't apply. Thank you for your help.

Comment: -1 for misleading title. Accepted solution has nothing to do with pipes or sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you have `$(shell echo '$$(@D)/')`; why not just write `$$(@D)/` directly?

As for the second one, it doesn't work because the `$(shell ...)` function is evaluated immediately, not during the second expansion.  You need to defer the shell function as well by writing `$$(shell ...)`.

However, I'm not sure that would work.  I don't understand why you're even doing this; I assume there's some larger context which makes it useful.  Because, you can do exactly what you want to do above *MUCH* more straightforwardly by using static pattern rules:

```
~/hello.txt : %/hello.txt : %/bye.txt
        echo "$^"
```